# Which applications use R-Trees?

Tags: tree, gis, r-tree

Besides GIS applications, which other applications or libraries use R-trees and its variants?

Comment: We used them to speed up the analysis of LIDAR scans: http://graphics.cs.msu.ru/en/science/research/3dpoint/classification

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Computer games often do.  [Here's a link to something cool](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MegaTexture#Future_Technology_Evolution).

Computer graphics - both software and hardware - often use spatial partitioning e.g. [BSP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_space_partitioning); there's neat logic in Imagination and Intel chips termed [tile or zone rendering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiled_rendering), for example.

Code I've seen tends to lean towards fixed resolution dividing - octtrees, typically - rather than variable size buckets, but I'd still consider them 'variants' of R-trees.

Answer (score 0):

Some relational databases use R-trees for indexing.

PostgreSQL is one example.
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/indexes-types.html

Comment: Most RDBMS support spatial extensions to support GIS applications.  Its not exactly that spatial indexes in databases are an end in themselves.

Answer (score -1):

[Here's an application](http://www.geoplace.com/ME2/dirmod.asp?sid=&nm=&type=MultiPublishing&mod=PublishingTitles&mid=13B2F0D0AFA04476A2ACC02ED28A405F&tier=4&id=C05F66CA29A246A68068ABCF65628799) -- a personal carbon calculator that resides within your smartphone -- using R-trees that are part of the Perst Lite open source embedded database.

Answer (score -2):

"R-trees have grown everywhere; from CAD and geographical databases to multimedia and time series management systems." http://www.rtreeportal.org/

about 2,620,00 results, 10.9 seconds to Google and post on SO

Comment: -1 Not very informative. About as helpful as a google search.